# PHP: understanding cache with dynamic concent and API

Tags: php, json, api, caching, dynamic

I have a php file, and I'm using an API where if I have an id, I can obtain data through the API. However, I'm currently learning how to create a cache system. The API data is retrieved through JSON data. So I was wondering, if its possible to constantly add JSON data to the existing cache file that already has JSON data in it, so when I have an id, next time I'll search the cache file that matches the id instead of searching the API (which has a limit like any API does).

Maybe create multiple arrays and search for the id key?

I hope someone can understand this? I'm still looking around to help me with a caching script, if anyone have any ideas where I can look, that'll be very helpfuul as well.

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way to cache is normally to use something like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) (which provides caching as well as other stuff).  You can store multiple cache entries, such as the results for ID 1, another entry for ID 2 and so on; you can then check if each entry is in the cache and then grab it from the API if not.  @mariotanenbaum's suggestion below, that you get the API fixed so that you can search multiple IDs in one request, is also a very sensible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do that. Cache is often based on time that passed from last request. And in your case, since you are requesting data via API, i think it would be the best to cache the result pafe for few minutes or to not cache it at all.

Comment: but what if i'm constantly getting new id data? say if a user likes something, they have more ids to get from the API. does the site know that there's only 1 new id (or new JSON data) and will get the rest of the data from the cached file? Or if there's one new changed item, the site will need to get all JSON data from API again?

Comment: so if user likes 3 different items (each item is associated with an id), then I would loop through the API with the id's and display the data. That means I'm already doing 3 calls from the API (which can get expensive), and then it gets stored into the cached file. So when the same user likes another item (4th id), then will the system know not to loop through all 3 previous ids and just cache it? Or does it start all over?

Comment: Can you do anything about that api, can you just pass all id's that you want and get condensed results with one request?

Comment: I don' think I can, maybe I can create a new cache file for each id? so if I do need to get a specific id, it'll look for the cache file with the associated name? What do you think? But what if theres like millions of ids? does that mean it'll generate millions of files? I think that would be bad huh?

Comment: :( i would investigate that API bit more, if it is good one, i believe they have that option. Otherwise, make one cache file and put the fetched results in it in this format: [id timestamp result] so all you need is explode string by " ", to check if wanted id exists there and if it is in proper time range, if so, get the result, decode it and return it to visitor, if it doesn't exist or if it is not in proper time range, just fetch new one via API, replace old one and return it to visitor. That loop would be quite fast and if you really insist it to be cached.